# What is the best dbms for a tracker/torrent-like service?

Tags: database

I'm developing a service that will track nodes over the internet. The service will order the list of nodes by DateTime and the database don't need to survive a crash ( http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.1#Unlogged_Tables ).

So, under these circumstances, what is the dbms that have the best performance?

NOTE: I'm not biased, so I can use SQL and NoSQL solutions.

NOTE2: I put "tracker/torrent-like" because the service acts like a tracker, and will be queried about ips and needs to have fast-access for all data (no items queried much more than others). It needs erase old nodes regularly too.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a lot of connections, if sheer speed it is whats needed, with no warranty of data being saved on disk. Your easiest, fastest and best option would be Redis in my opinion.

http://redis.io/

It covers all your needs. This might be an old question, but maybe someone else might come here looking for the answer.

Comment: Does redis support range operations on DateTime objects (put link)? For this project, I think I couldn't use redis efficiently without this feature.

Comment: Actually Redis is a Key Value Data Store, so it all depends on your "schema" of sorts, but it does support what you ask as range operations on ANY key. It is probably the fastest data store around, so you shouldn't worry about doing like 10 operations to get your data (which can be grouped in a transaction) as it is 100x faster than most SQL solutions. For example you can have SortedSet of "DateTime" values, and just select a range when you need. Check out the link, you won't regret it.

http://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro

Comment: Oh I just remembered something about your second note and it is the reason I'm using redis for a project. You can set EXPIRE on a key, so unless you access them and set it again, old values will be deleted automatically when the time comes. Thats pretty useful IMO.

Comment: [Try redis](http://try.redis.io/) taught me the very basics of Redis and it mentions EXPIRE (very useful), but all range operations work on integer indexes and integer indexes are invalidated after the first modification. I wanna use DateTime indexes in my tracker.

Comment: Depends on what are you programming, but DateTime is normally a stylish representation of an integer Unix Timestamp, all DateTime fields are usually just that 64 bit integers that get parsed nicelly into a date and time.

Comment: Integers don't solve my problem, I need a value with semantic. Anyway... Redis seems fine. I found [this out](http://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore). All I need to do now is profile to see how much I gain from Redis.

Comment: I don't get why the database should store DateTime with semantics as you shouldn't be working with them. Most programming languages have functions to convert a DateTime object into a POSIX timestamp and viceversa. The semantics should be on your code. Here is a simple example in python on using DateTime as score (integer) on a Sorted Set an selecting a range via zrangebyscore: http://deathofagremmie.com/archive/2011/12/1/

Comment: The database don't need to store DateTime objects, but the range operations shouldn't be the classic integer-style array indexing. [ZRANGE](http://redis.io/commands/zrange) is useless for my application, because after the first modification the indexes are invalidated. Redis can solve my problem with [ZRANGEBYSCORE](http://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore).

Comment: Glad it helped you. You can also use [ZREVRANGEBYSCORE](http://redis.io/commands/zrevrangebyscore) to get your data sorted the other way around (sometimes you want to process newer dates first instead of older ones).

Comment: Thank you. At some point I lost the hope that this question would be answered. It was my fault anyway (poor description).

Comment: I finally implemented the project: https://github.com/blowthemall/blowthemall-nodejs